# How to replace characters matching a specific condition on a 2d matrix in c?

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, random

So i have a code that loads a textfile into a 2d array. The textfile contains a grid of this form:

```
+---------+    +------+
|..........####.......| 
|.........|    |......|
+----------    +______+
```

Now what i want my code to do is to check if there is any spot on the grid with the character '.' and randomly replace it with the character '*'. But the thing is that, I'm not replacing all the '.' characters. I can replace any number of them and they have to be randomly selected. So for instance, supposing I want to replace 5 random spots on the grid, this would be my expected output:

```
+---------+    +------+
|...*......####.....*.| 
|*.....*..|    |.*....|
+----------    +______+
```

This is what I tried but it didn't work as expected. I would be glad if anybody could point me in the right direction.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct grid {
    char **gridArray;
    size_t row;
    size_t col;
} grid_t;

grid_t *
grid_new(size_t length, size_t height)
{
    grid_t *grid = malloc(sizeof(grid_t));
    assert(grid != NULL);
    char ** a = malloc(sizeof(char *) * length);
    assert(a != NULL);
    grid->gridArray = a;
    grid->row = length;
    grid->col = height;

    for (size_t n = 0; n < length; n++){
        grid->gridArray[n] = malloc(sizeof(char) * height);
        assert(grid->gridArray[n] != NULL);
    }

    return grid;
}

bool
emptySpot(grid_t * map, int x, int y);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    grid_t *grid = grid_new(r, rowCol);
    /* replace 7 '.' spots with '*' */
    for (int m = 0; m < 7; m++){
        while (1){
            int randNumRow = (rand() % (grid->row + 1));  // generates random x value between 0 and max number of rows
            int randNumCol = (rand() % (grid->col + 1));  // generates random y value between 0 and max number of cols
            if (emptySpot(grid, randNumRow, randNumCol)){
                grid->gridArray[randNumRow][randNumCol] = '*';  // drop '*' in empty spot on grid
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 1;
}


bool
emptySpot(grid_t *map, int x, int y)
{
    if (map->gridArray[x][y] == '.'){  // if spot on grid is empty, return true
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to include code for reading files for this question. Please create a [mre]

Comment: +1 for a clean compile with zero warnings.  When using `rand()`, it is typically worth considering a single call to [srand()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_srand.htm) first.

Comment: I typically use `rows` and `cols` as the variable names for the matrix dimensions, and `r` and `c` as the indices into the matrix, e.g. `for (r = 0; r < rows; r++)`. I think if you use those names consistently throughout the code, the problems will disappear.

Comment: In this line: `int randNumCol = (rand() % (grid->col + 1));  // generates random y value between 0 and max number of cols`, the value of `grid->col + 1` is 25, causing a `Dereference of out-of-bounds pointer: 1 bytes (1 elements) past end of array.` ***here:***  `if (map->gridArray[x][y] == '.'){  // if spot on grid is empty, return true`  Note that the number of columns for the example grid is actually `23`, so indexing should be limited to `0` - `22`.

Comment: @ryyker I'm now able to fill 7 spots on the grid with '*' but I have a little issue now. Those spots remain the same anytime i run the code. Is there something I need to do with the random function to randomize the 7 spots on the grid?

Comment: Yes, call `srand(clock());` once, in `main()` should work.

Comment: @ryyker thanks a lot! It works now.

Comment: FWIW, The very first comment says _"There's no need to include code for reading files for this question"_.  In this case I do not agree.  Being able to reproduce your code, and an input file matching your example code helped to quickly identify the items that needed attention in your code.  Removing the _file read_ code would have hindered those discoveries.